# POST request to server returning a 403 error in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, request, http-status-code-403

I'm building a login page where the user, by entering username and password and clicking on the "Login" button, is authenticated and logged into the app.

When the user taps the "Login" button, two calls are made to the server:
1- GET call to retrieve and save the value of a cookie.

2- POST call in which the response is a redirect towards a fictitious URL. Then I have to handle the invalid schema exception in the call and retrieve the value of the ACCESS_TOKEN parameter (the OAuth token).

I expect a 302 response but what returns is a 403 status code.

Maybe I'm making some errors when building the body of the request.
This is the function I use to make the POST call:

```
-(void) makeLoginRequest {

// Setting url
NSString *urlForLogin = @"https://www.endpointforlogin.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlForLogin];
//Initializing the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
// Setting request method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:request.URL];
NSDictionary *headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

    
//Building the body of the request
self.csfrToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:KEY_CSRF_TOKEN];

NSArray *parameters = @[
  @{ @"name": @"username", @"value": self.emailTextField.text },
  @{ @"name": @"password", @"value": self.passwordTextField.text },
  @{ @"name": @"_csrf", @"value": self.csfrToken },
  @{ @"name": @"sender", @"value": @"UAPP-12345678909876543210123456" },
  @{ @"name": @"client_id", @"value": @"mobile" }
];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
    [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
    [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"]];
    [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain;\r\n\r\n"];
    [body appendFormat:@"%@\r\n", param[@"value"]];
}
[body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    if (error) {
      NSString *errorMsg = error.userInfo[@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
      errorMsg = (errorMsg) ? errorMsg : NSLocalizedString(@"unexpected_error", nil);
      [Util displayOnMainThreadAlertFromController:self withMessage:errorMsg];
        switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
            case 200: // http request status OK, I'm going over the switch
            break;
            case 500: // internal server error
            [Util displayOnMainThreadAlertFromController:self withMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"internal_server_error", nil)];
            return;
            default: // unexpected status code
            NSLog(@"(long)httpResponse.statusCode unexpected: %ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
            [Util displayOnMainThreadAlertFromController:self withMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"unexpected_error", nil)];
        return;
        }
    } else {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
        switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
            case 302:
            break;
            case 403:
            NSLog(@"(long)httpResponse.statusCode : %ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
                [Util displayOnMainThreadAlertFromController:self withMessage:@"Errore 403!"];
            break;
            default: // unexpected status code
            NSLog(@"(long)httpResponse.statusCode non previsto: %ld", (long)httpResponse.statusCode);
            [Util displayOnMainThreadAlertFromController:self withMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"unexpected_error", nil)];
            return;
        }
    }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

}

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Is `request` headers correct? Do you have the correct token put there? Should you had as a headerfiel that you're doing a multiform part request? And also give the boundary (as we usually do)? Can you make it work in POSTMAN?

Comment: @Larme I'm using NSHTTPCookieStorage and NSHTTPCookie to save cookies but I don't know if they're working properly. How can I check it?
I've tried to do it on POSTMAN using the same parameters but it even returns me 403 error.

Comment: Print the fields https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/1418477-allhttpheaderfields?language=objc and check the doc of your API, you might be missing some parameters...

Comment: You should ask yours API provider